# Upload Avro to BigQuery Provided Schema does not match Table x. Field big_numeric_col has changed type from BIGNUMERIC(40, 2) to NUMERIC

Tags: .net, google-bigquery, avro

Attempting to load data to BigQuery using an Avro file. The column is defined in BigQuery as BIGNUMERIC(40,2).The Avro schema doesn't have a way to disambiguate between NUMERIC and BIGNUMERIC. I'm using the .NET BigQueryClient.UploadAvroAsync and that API doesn't provide a mechanism to disambiguate, either. The REST API which has a decimalTargetTypes[] property, but that requires a separate step to upload the file to Google Cloud.

It appears that the code underlying UploadAvroAsync() has the ability to specify the decimalTargeTypes but the necessary method is private.

I can't use CSV because the data also includes arrays and may include structures.

I did try the "sqlType" property in the Avro schema but that seems to have been ignored.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way to do this is via decimalTargeTypes, I'm not familiar with the C# API but requesting a public facing API to set these (or asking if one might already exists) would be the only way to fix this.